# Pandas: Extract numerical values after keywords substrings of inconsistent delimiters & irregular orders and transform keywords & numbers to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text-extraction

I have an irregularly formatted database with the dataframe looks as follows:

| Area | Dimensions |
| --- | --- |
| foo | Length: 2m; Width: 3m; Height: 4m; Slope- 3 |
| bar | Width: 6m; Length: 4m; Height: 3m; Slope: 6 |
| baz | Height: 4m; Slope: 4; Volume = 24m3 |
| qux | Vol: 42m3 |

The delimiters are consistently semi-colons, but the colons may be replaced by some other symbol such as a dash or an equal sign. The order of the values are also inconsistent, so `str.split` was not effective.  I would like to extract as much information as I can from the `Dimensions` column and leave 0/Null values for values not specified.

I would like it to look as follows:

| Area | Length | Width | Height | Slope | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | NULL |
| bar | 4 | 6 | 3 | 6 | NULL |
| baz | NULL | NULL | 4 | 4 | 24 |
| qux | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 42 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New Version:

Main enhancement of new version is to substantially simplify the creation of keyword-value table.  Text extraction regex is also simplified to without specifying a set of predefined keywords.

#### Use [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) + [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), as follows:

1. Extract the `Dimensions` keywords and values by [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) into a list of key-value pairs tuples
2. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) these key-value pairs tuples to `dict` and create a dataframe
3. Join `Area` column with the newly created keyword-value dataframe by [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
# replace 'Vol' to 'Volume` 
# extract `Dimensions` keywords and numeric values into tuples of paired values
dim_extract = (df['Dimensions'].str.replace(r'Vol\b', 'Volume', regex=True)
                               .str.findall(r'(\w+)\W+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\w*(?:;|$)')
              )

# map key-value pairs to `dict` and create a dataframe
keyword_df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, dim_extract))

# Optionally convert the extracted dimension values from string to float or integer format 
#keyword_df = keyword_df.apply(pd.to_numeric)                    # convert to float
#keyword_df = keyword_df.apply(pd.to_numeric).astype('Int64')    # convert to integer

# join `Area` column with newly created keyword dataframe
df_out = df[['Area']].join(keyword_df)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Area Length Width Height Slope Volume
0  foo      2     3      4     3    NaN
1  bar      4     6      3     6    NaN
2  baz    NaN   NaN      4     4     24
3  qux    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     42
```

#### Old Version:

#### Use [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) + [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as follows:

1. Extract the `Dimensions` keywords and values by [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) into a list of key-value pairs tuples
2. Transform each element in the list to a row by [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)
3. Further separate the paired values of `Dimensions` keywords and values from a tuple into individual columns
4. Transform the `Dimensions` keywords into columns by [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
# replace 'Vol' to 'Volume` 
# extract `Dimensions` keywords and numeric values into tuples of paired values
df['extract'] = (df['Dimensions'].str.replace(r'Vol\b', 'Volume', regex=True)
                                 .str.findall(r'(Length|Width|Height|Slope|Volume)\W+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\w*(?:;|$)')
                )

# Transform each element in the list to a row
df2 = df.explode('extract')

# Separate the `Dimensions` keywords and values from a tuple into individual columns 
df2['col_name'], df2['col_val'] = zip(*df2['extract'])

# Optionally convert the extracted dimension values from string to float or integer format 
#df2['col_val'] = df2['col_val'].astype(float)
#df2['col_val'] = df2['col_val'].astype(int)

# Transform the `Dimensions` keywords into columns 
df_out = df2.pivot(index='Area', columns='col_name', values='col_val').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Area Height Length Slope Volume Width
0  bar      3      4     6    NaN     6
1  baz      4    NaN     4     24   NaN
2  foo      4      2     3    NaN     3
3  qux    NaN    NaN   NaN     42   NaN
```